# How do I share full-resolution photos between Apple devices?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, photos, file-sharing

As the title states, I need to know a way of sending full-resolution photos from one Apple device to another (iPhone to iPhone/iPad/Mac) but don't want to lose quality at all.

I'm guessing photos get downsized in iMessage. What about AirDrop? What about sharing a photo album via iCloud?

Does anyone know the definitive answer?

Comment: Removed the "best" part from the question. It creates some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airdrop sends full sized versions.

~iCloud link/album sharing sends full size versions.~ shared album is 2048 pixels for normal photos. 5000 px for panorama.

iMessages can downsize if enabled in Message settings, but I don't know otherwise.

Put them in a note and add collaborators or create a sharable link.

Put them in iCloud Drive and share from there.

Use Dropbox, Firefox Send, Google Drive, OneDrive.

Plug in the iPhone to a Mac, trust the device and import using Photos.app. And then export unmodified original or let it do so modifications.

Comment: iCloud shared albums downsize the photos.

Comment: Downvote for incorrect information. iCloud shared album reduces photos to 2048px according to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202786

Answer (score 0):

If your devices support it, please consider testing the new **iOS 13** features.
With iOS 13 users are finally (!!!) allowed to **use a USB key** to copy files without using an external app. The iOS "Finder" (Files app) is yet planned to do it properly.

Answer (score -1):

@anki is correct : [iCloud link](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/mm93a9b98683/icloud) let us share full size versions of photos and videos. You can create an iCloud link for selected photos/videos, or for an entire album. The only drawback is that each link expires after 30 days, it's not possible to make it permanent.

Comment: This answer seems to be the same as your [other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/471376/100490). Are the questions the same?