# Sharing full resolution photos

Tags: iphone, photos

My friend has and iPhone 12 max and I don't.

Using her phone, she selected the photos and videos and shared them to me by creating a link.

Using the link, I could download the photos in a zip.

All except 1 photo was 3MP (2048x1536) and one was 12MP.  All videos except two were 720 MP4 except two which were 1080 MOV.  When I tried downloading just one photo, it would say it was downloading a HEIC though it would give me a JPG.

She also tried going to icloud.com and repeating the procedure and still only got 3MP.  The only thing that worked was choosing to email but that isn't practical.

How can she share everything full resolution?  Searching around, people say sharing a link is the way to share full resolution but that isn't working.

Comment: Are you checking on iPhone (which), Mac, PC...?

Comment: I am checking on a PC via web browser.  being sent from a iphone 12 max

Comment: HEIC isn't supported on PC. Is the conversion being done at her end (Check in iPhone > Settings > Photos > Transfer to Mac or PC > Is it set to Automatic or Original?) or on the PC while opening (with HEIF Image Extension or CopyTrans or such convertor?) This may provide some clues.

Comment: This is the message I'm seeing on the icloud website when downloading from the icloud link.  Eventhough it says this, it gives me a JPEG.  So maybe icloud is doing the conversion or its an erroneous message.  Checking the file I receive from icloud, it is a jpeg.  I thought icloud was always supposed to hold the full resolution image.  Strangely enough, emailing works telling me the full versions do exist on the phone.  It gives me a .JPG instead of a .JPEG (from icloud).  They should be the same thing but maybe that's a clue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share full-resolution photos between Apple devices?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370903/how-do-i-share-full-resolution-photos-between-apple-devices)

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://www.macworld.com/article/342577/how-to-maintain-video-resolution-when-sharing-videos-via-airdrop.html), it may solve the problem.

My guess is that the lower resolution items contain edits. Edited HEICs are exported as JPEGs.

Comment: no she did not edit them and sending via email worked.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any type of iPhone you she could send them to you via Airdrop which should send the full res images.

Comment: Airdrop is not compatible with non-Apple products

Comment: Then you should have said you had an Android phone, all you said was that you didn't have an iPhone 12 Pro Max

Answer (score 0):

[iCloud link](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/mm93a9b98683/icloud) let us share full size versions of photos and videos. You can create an iCloud link for selected photos/videos, or for an entire album. The only drawback is that each link expires after 30 days, it's not possible to make it permanent.

Comment: This answer seems to be the same as your [other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/471375/100490). Are the questions the same?

Comment: If you find duplicate questions, flag for review as a duplicate.  Don’t write/post identical answers